# Is there any way in spring for logging queries of specific JPA repository?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, logback

I have several JPA repositories in a package and I want to log queries of only one specific repository. I know there are following properties in spring:

1. logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
2. logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

But these properties log sql statements of all the repositories. I want these properties to work only for given repository. Is there a way in spring to configure for such requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature in Spring. What you could do is writing a wrapper or a proxy, wrapping the repositories in question and before each call setting a value in the [MDC](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) and use that for filtering by writing an [`EvaluatorFilter`](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#evalutatorFilter) accessing the [MDC of the `ILoggingEvent`](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/ILoggingEvent.html#getMDCPropertyMap())

Something similar should be possible with other Logging frameworks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was thinking about similar workaround but that is too much for logging of one repository. I wanted to know if there is any sort of configuration provided by Spring.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring, you could achieve this using "logback.xml" (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html).

In the logback.xml you can specify package/class log levels,

ex: `<logger name="org.test.project.yourRepository" level="DEBUG"/>`

Comment: Thanks for the response but, this configuration does not work for JPA or Hibernate because as far as i know their logging is applied at application level. Due to which queries of all repositories is logged, i only want logging of only given repository.

Comment: This doesn't work, because the logging doesn't actually come from the repository classes (they are just interfaces), but from the underlying persistence framework (Hibernate).